# How do I query by nested Refs in objectify

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I have this structure:

```
//////Entity to be filtered
public class StockItem{
@Index
private Ref<StockItemTypeEntity> stockItemType;
} `enter code here`
```

and

```
//////Ref
public class StockItemTypeEntity{
@Index
private Ref<StockItemProductTypeEntity> productType;
}
```

I want to filter `StockItem` like this:

```
stockItemQuery = stockItemQuery.filter("stockItemType.productType", fitlerWrapper.getProductType());
```

But this isn't working. How do I filter using nested Refs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a join, which is not supported by the underlying datastore. That is to say, if you want to perform a join you have to do it yourself.

Depending on the shape of your data and what you are trying to do, one common solution is to denormalize the index data into the parent entity (index a 'productType' field in the StockItem). It does require keeping the data in sync.